# Why isn't instrumental/numerical precision classified as systematic error?

Tags: standard-error, error, measurement-error, precision

Sorry if my question is insultingly elementary, or if this isn't the right place to ask this. Though it's really just a matter of semantics, this question has been bugging me for quite some time.

Suppose you're measuring some quantity with some instrument. The raw precision of your measuring instrument and/or the numerical precision of your calculator is an error that is present in every measurement you take, and it will never go away no matter how many measurements you take. For example, if you're measuring the length of a paper with a ruler, and the ruler-person combination doesn't allow for measurements more precise than $0.5\text{mm}$, then you will never know the length of that paper to a better precision of $0.5\text{mm}$ (assuming all other factors are controlled). The same argument can be applied to numerical precision.

Therefore, it seems natural to say that this type of error is systematic with respect to the quantity we are measuring. To classify it as a random/statistical error you would have to say that this error is centered around the true value, but you can't say that here. Of course, if you're calculating the effect of this quantity on another quantity, then the error in the measurement of that effect introduced by this imprecision can definitely be reduced by repeated measurements, so I would say that this type of error is statistical with respect to, in general, another derived quantity.

However, I've always heard that this sort of error is statistical/random. Why is that?

Comment: Speaking of the intuition, if a ruler man always overestimates the length because he does not have the culture of using the ruler properly, this is systematic (whether negative or positive). If the ruler man tries his best, but due to small nuances in each experiment (random factors) his measurements tend to vary +- independently of each other measurement he made, this is a random variable, i.e., a variable that contains some noise.

Comment: By implying that "imprecision" might not be "centered around the true value," you do not seem to use "precision" in its usual sense in this question.  Any such deviation from zero would ordinarily be termed *inaccuracy*.  You also assert something that is untrue: enough independent measurements with poor precision can be used to make an estimate that has arbitrarily good precision.  That's a Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: @whuber pointed to a distinction between accuracy and precision, [here](https://labwrite.ncsu.edu/Experimental%20Design/accuracyprecision.htm)'s a link explaining it

Comment: @whuber Okay I accidentally misused the term "precision". But regarding your second point (i.e. the law of large numbers), could you please tell me how that counter what I said in my post, i.e. how using an ordinary ruler and an indefinite number of trials a human could obtain an accurate estimate of the length of an ordinary paper with a precision of $1\mu m$?

Comment: It is unlikely that repeated measurements by a single human being using a single ruler would truly be independent.  But to the extent they are, and to the extent we can expect mathematics to model the real world correctly, the Law of Large Numbers explains how and why the average of one million separate *accurate* measurements of that paper using a ruler with (say) 1 mm *precision* would itself still be accurate and have 1 micron precision.

Comment: @whuber Okay true about the independency of repeated single person measurements. Let's change the situation to an indefinite number of people each making a single independent measurement. Look, I know that the standard error in a mean goes down as $1/\sqrt{N}$, but that presupposes that every measurement comes from a continuous distribution, which by the finite resolution of a ruler is violated. My belief is that the law of large numbers would still apply, **but to no finer a resolution than the underlying sample space,** so it's impossible to measure a paper's length to $1\mu m$ with a ruler.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, by the way, for your comments so far.

Comment: The inverse square root law does not presuppose a continuous distribution: it only supposes the distribution has a finite variance.  A standard example concerns estimating the prevalence of a trait in a large population: the random variable is as far from continuous as you can get--it can have only two values--yet the prevalence can be estimated to several decimal places provided only that the test for the trait is accurate. Your argument about "no finer resolution" would fly in the face of this (rather obvious) result by concluding we could never estimate the prevalence!

Comment: @whuber No, you missed my point. Just as in determining the prevalence of a trait in a large population, we can also determine the prevalence of the length of our paper being $10.9\text{in}$, $11\text{in}$, $11.1\text{in}$, etc. With repeated measurements we can refine this prevalence to arbitrary precision. However, in the context of your example, you can never say "and therefore on average this organism has $1/2$ of trait $X$!" This wouldn't make sense. To say such a thing would require a change in the underlying model, i.e. trait $X$ would have to become at least a ternary variable.

Comment: (continuing) What you can say, of course, is "and therefore an organism will have trait $X$ with probability $P$!"

Comment: The prevalence of a trait is as much of a property of a population as the length of paper is a property of the paper.  Of course no *individual* in the population has $0.5$ of a trait--and equally obviously, if the ruler measures only in integral multiples of 1 mm, it will never yield a value that is a fraction of that.  Nevertheless, in both cases the average of many independent accurate observations will estimate that *property* with higher precision than any individual observation. This conclusion has nothing whatsoever to do with the discreteness or continuity of the error distribution.

Comment: @whuber My basic point is that there's no way you can give rulers to an indefinite number of people and produce a highly precise measurement of a single molecule. I'm saying that that can't happen. If you can tell me how that can happen then my erroneous logic will be set straight (assuming I wrong, which from previous experience is very likely).

Comment: Physical impracticability is *completely irrelevant* to theoretical results or logical reasoning.  If you really mean to be asking about impracticability, then you need to completely change your question (a) to clarify that this is its focus and (b) to describe exactly what physical applications you are interested in.

Comment: Yes, the highly precise measurements are produced by repeated measurements. Look at the [Higgs boson paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.7214.pdf). They accumulated enough events to claim that the particle exists and its weight is 125 GeV.