# Measuring the size of a molecule with a ruler and enough independent measurements?

Tags: error, accuracy, measurement-error, precision

This question arose from the conversation on [a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305949/why-isnt-instrumental-numerical-precision-classified-as-systematic-error?noredirect=1#comment581746_305949) of mine. Also, I purposely came up with a ridiculous attention-grabbing title and question to facilitate the discussion more easily. I am not actually interested in measuring the size of a molecule with a ruler.

**[Here is the seeming paradox]:** Give a ruler to somebody and try to measure the size of a molecule with a ruler. They will get some reading $x=s+\delta$, where $s$ is the true value and $\delta$ is the error. If there are no systematic errors, then the error $\delta$ solely comes from instrument imprecision and human clumsiness/incapacity, and thus it is random. Now give rulers to a huge number of people, enough for the law of large numbers to well be valid, and get an independent measurement from each of them. The error in the average that you obtain from this huge sample goes down by $1/\sqrt{N}$. Thus, since you are certain no systematic average-shifting errors are present, the average of all those measurements gives you the true value of the size of the molecule with a precision of $1/\sqrt{N}$.

**[Here is my attempted resolution]:** Although each size-measurement is in principle a random drawing from a continuous distribution, the finite resolution of our measurement device effectively puts each size-measurement into a bin, making each measurement discrete in a certain sense. For example, if our resolution was $1\text{mm}$, this is the distribution we would get:

[image]

In this case, I believe all we can is that the probability of receiving a measurement $x=0\text{mm}$ is $100\%$, and we can say that with a relative precision of $1/\sqrt{N}$. Since the resolution of our ruler was $1\text{mm}$ to start with, we can therefore say the true molecule-size is within the range $(0\text{mm},1\text{mm})$ with $1/\sqrt{N}$ precision, **which is equivalent to just saying our uncertainty in measuring the molecule-size is $1\text{mm}$, as it intuitively was all along.**

**[My question:]** I know all of this may seem stupid and contrived, but I am really struggling to understand how in **this particular case** my reasoning is flawed, i.e. how we really can measure the size of a molecule with enough people and rulers. I believe I am wrong because every well-qualified source ([see linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305949/why-isnt-instrumental-numerical-precision-classified-as-systematic-error?noredirect=1#comment581746_305949)) seems to say otherwise, which I personally don't understand.

**[Important Qualifiers]:**

1. To be totally clear, I am **not** talking about estimating the **probability** of obtaining discrete measurements (e.g. $0\text{mm}$, $1\text{mm}$, etc.). That is obviously a measurement that can be refined indefinitely with more samples (in principle). I am talking about refining a histogram, which from the outset is partitioned into slots of size equal to the measurement resolution, into a finer partitioning through repeated measurements. To me this doesn't seem to be possible, but once again, all sources seem to indicate otherwise.
2. Please do not just say "Sorry bud, it's a mathematical fact that repeated measurements refine the precision of the final averaged measurement. It's called standard error of the mean, and it drops off as $1/\sqrt{N}$. Look at how precisely scientists have measured $X$ phenomenon." I obviously know that. That is why I've constructed a single contrived case to highlight my misunderstanding.
3. The context of my question is that I am a TA for a freshman physics lab, and many students have asked whether instrument precision is a statistical error or systematic error. I told them it is a statistical error, since its effect when determining derived quantities is diminished through repeated measurements, or more simply put, you can handle it with statistics. But now after thinking more about it, I'm a little confused myself, and that made me post [the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305949/why-isnt-instrumental-numerical-precision-classified-as-systematic-error?noredirect=1#comment581746_305949), which led me to this question.

Comment: The situation you posit is too ridiculous to permit meaningful dialog: the assumptions it makes cannot possibly hold and, as the lengthy comments in your previous question attempt to explain, there are important distinctions between physical reality and mathematical fact.  Before you can draw meaningful conclusions from mathematics, you need to check that the assumptions are physically realistic.  As such the internal inconsistencies in this question simply further the confusion created by the original question.  Please choose a better example if you wish to illuminate the subject.

Comment: I think the best course of action is to send your students to CV, and let them ask their questions directly.

Comment: Perhaps I can be clearer about the contradictions: your analysis, accepting its validity for the purposes of discussion, demonstrates that the ruler is *biased*: if it can only ever produce a result of zero on target objects that are sufficiently small (like atoms), then its expectation is zero for such objects.  This creates essential confusion between precision and accuracy and between measurement and expectation.  These render the rest of the post incoherent.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much! Now that you point it out, I'm positive that's where I was going wrong, i.e. in failing to recognize that there is obviously bias (on the order of $1\text{mm}$) in each ruler measurement. This systematic bias, which is present in every measurement, is certainly a systematic error.

Comment: @whuber OP states there's no systematic errors, then immediately proceeded to state that probability of 0mm measurement is 1. That's clearly a contradiction, since bias is the systematic error of the measurement. So OP's equation is contradictory too, it has to be $x=\mu+s+\delta$, where $\mu$ is the bias or systematic error. In this case it's easy to say what is the bias, it's the size of the molecule

Comment: @Aksakal Yes, you're right. I failed to identify that the resolution of the measuring device imposes a bias on each measurement, which is a systematic error, which as you point out is in contradiction with my assumption that there are no systematic errors.

Comment: Arturo, I believe bias in a measurement system is a subtle thing that usually cannot be characterized with a single value.  In the case of the ruler it's quite possible that the bias is nonzero only for invisible objects (and huge objects).  After that, @Aksal's argument (now deleted) applies: on average, it may be that the measurements are perfectly correct.  In the laboratory, then, we tend to be concerned about *calibration,* which is the process of estimating the bias as a function of the true value and then inverting that to make good guesses of the true value based on the measurement.

Comment: (Cont'd) Your example of measuring the atom is perhaps better conceived of as a *detection limit* problem.  Such problems are usually resolved in a calibration context.  The calibration permits us to establish statistical criteria related to the confidence that an object actually has any length at all (detectability) or the confidence that its length can be measured with an acceptable precision and accuracy (quantifiability).

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I agree and I'm glad you bring up those points. To tie it back to the example you gave in my previous question, in estimating the prevalence of a trait in an entire population, one would need to calibrate the measured prevalence in a sample of the population by taking into account how that sample fits into the distribution of the entire population. This, of course, is otherwise known as *selection bias*. It'd probably be good if you formed all this into an answer so I can accept it and have this question marked as resolved. :)